# Cron Job for php file is not working on some file

Tags: php, linux, cron

I was setting up a crop job to run the PHP script to send emails from the database.

```
*/1 * * * * php -q /home/kabilan/cs2062/Project/Master/CS2062/PHP/PHPMailer/cron.php
```

This is the task command I set in crontab. I'm quite sure that there is no mistake in this because I tried it with some other random scripts which don't involve in database or any complex code.

cron.php :

```
require_once '../Result/Database.php';
require_once 'Mail.php';

$mailDatabase = Database::getdb();
$mailList = $mailDatabase->getMailUser();

foreach ($mailList as $mailDetail) {
   $email = $mailDetail[0];
   ...
   ...
```

When I try to run this script manually, it works perfectly fine but the cron task doesn't seem to do anything here. What might be the problem here? And also suggest, if there are any way to see the result of a cron task like this.

Comment: Maybe you're relying on being in a certain working directory; or maybe the cronjob runs as a different user than you're manually doing now (and has different access limitations).

Comment: Redirect output to a file and check the file. Add `> /home/kabilan/output.txt 2>&1` to the end of the command.

Comment: Thanks to @Barmar , I found the problem here. When adding another file using require_once I used relative path. But when the Cron task runs from the command line it takes the path from the location of the PHP.  I used the absolute path to solve the issue and tried to use relative path from the location of the PHP, that also worked.